# Frozen monitor problem in a multi monitor setup (16.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, hdmi, amd-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and noticed a strange behavior which is described below.

I have a three monitor setup where my primary monitor (1) is attached to my primary graphic card (an AMD R9 270X) by DisplayPort, my projector (2) is also attached to the primary graphic card by HDMI, and my secondary monitor (3) is connected to the integrated chip from my Intel I7-2600K processor by HDMI.

When I start my system Ubuntu starts like normal and all screens are showing the Ubuntu logo and the dynamic progress bar below. However when I reach the login screen on my primary monitor (1), I still see the Ubuntu logo and a frozen progress bar on 2. And this screen is frozen until (from what I have noticed) two events happen:

- The timer for "Turn screen off when inactive" kicks in

  When this happens all screen go black, and when I move the mouse all three monitors wake up again, and from this moment on all three monitors are behaving normally.
- I suspend the system

  If I suspend the system, and then wake it up all three monitors are also behaving normally.

I'm looking for some help to troubleshoot this error, since I don't want to suspend or wait for the "Turn screen off when inactive" to kick in before I can use all monitors.